# Action script mobile project. how to add datespinner

Tags: actionscript-3

How should I add dateSpinner component to action script mobile project?

Answer (score 0):

As a Flex component, `DateSpinner` is only available from the `spark.components` package; therefore, not included in pure ActionScript projects.

Implemented within the Flex framework, the spinner is rendered from Flash for ubiquitous delivery across multiple platforms.

Although there may be native extensions, AIR does not expose native controls such as UIDatePicker.

If you're using Adobe Flash Builder, instead of an ActionScript Mobile Project, you could create a Flex based application:

[image: flex-mobile-project]

An example MXML implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               applicationDPI="160">

    <s:DateSpinner id="dateSpinner"
                   displayMode="dateAndTime"
                   selectedDate="{new Date(2013, 3, 12)}"
                   minDate="{new Date(2013, 0, 1)}"
                   maxDate="{new Date(2013, 11, 31)}"
                   minuteStepSize="5" />

</s:Application>
```

Would then produce the following:

[image: date-spinner]

Comment: sorry for the dumb question. but i didn't understend the solution "Implemented within the Flex framework, the spinner is rendered from Flash for ubiquitous delivery across multiple platforms." is there away to add flex framework to my project?

Comment: Thanks again man, but i have build 80% of my game. and i cant destroy it now and start over... if there is some other way u can think of, it will be real apricate. i m in deep s...t with that.

Comment: It's only available for Flex and you couldn't even get away with importing the Flex libraries because most components require the entire project be Flex (whereas you can utilize a lot of Flex Utils in a AS3 project). You could just build one yourself. It's not too difficult. Hardest part would be kinetic scrolling, which you should look at the Greensock ThrowProps plugin for.